# Is there a way querying alias and partition together?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I want to querying like

`select enp.LAST_NAME from EMPLOYEES enp partition("P20120101");`

When I try It oracle says;

```
> ORA-00924: missing BY keyword
```

Is there a way to use alias and partition together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

`FROM <TABLE_NAME> PARTITION(<PARTITION_NAME>) <ALIAS_NAME>`

So,
try `select enp.LAST_NAME from EMPLOYEES partition("P20120101") enp;`